# How to use retired version of Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: qt, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, qt4, qt4.8

Is there any way to load retired version (3.28 or 3.29) of Google maps APIs (free/paid options) ?

My Qt4 application uses QWebKit to load web content. Which is atleast few years old. Newest APIs versions are causing problems in my application. Since the last few days I am not able to load any API version older than 3.30.

If I specify 3.29 google gives me 3.31 or latest stable if I don't specify any version.

Even if I fix my current issues with latest versions, future updates in Maps API will cause more issues. I want to make sure I can load a specific version that will work with my application all the time.

Please reply, if you are aware of any methods.

Comment: No.  There are only ever 3 versions available [(frozen, release, experimental)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions).  Once they are retired, they are gone.